# Building email lists

Tags: email, unsubscribe

I am not new to Drupal but I am new to CiviCRM. I am building an email list, Does CiviCRM remove or scrub email lists?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if civicrm uses the same words so I'm just going to guess a bit what you're asking:

What I think you mean is if the email address is wrong or the email bounces, does it stop sending to them. Yes in general. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/maintaining-healthy-email-lists/

If you mean removing duplicates, it has features for that - see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/

If by scrubbing you mean cleaning up the data so it's more consistent, you may need an extension. Which one depends on what your concerns are. One example is https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividesk-normalize